# WPF DependencyProperty binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

In a WPF project, I have a user control called FlowControl.xaml which has a DependencyProperty called SetPointValue.

```
public static DependencyProperty SetPointValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SetPointValue", typeof(double), typeof(FlowControl), new PropertyMetadata(0d));

public double SetPointValue {
    get { return (double)GetValue(SetPointValueProperty); }
    set {
        SetValue(SetPointValueProperty, (double)value);

        CalcSetPointMargin();

        // Fire off any registered event handlers for the flow set point changing
        OnSetPointChanged?.Invoke(this, 
            new SetPointEventArgs(SetPointValue));
    }
}
```

You can see in the setter above that there is some business logic occurring any time SetPointvalue is set.

I am using the FlowControl in a window like this:

```
<cl:FlowControl x:Name="flowUC" SetPointValue="{Binding DataContext.FlowSetPointValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

You can see in the code above that I am binding the SetPointValue DependencyProperty to a property called FlowSetPointValue in the data context, which is a view model class called LrsVM.cs. Here is the FlowSetPointValue in the view model.

```
private double _flowSetPointValue { get; set; }
public double FlowSetPointValue {
    get {
        return _flowSetPointValue;
    }
    set {
        _flowSetPointValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FlowSetPointValue");
    }
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve here is **any time the FlowSetPointValue property is set in the view model then I want the business logic (mentioned earlier) in the setter of the SetPointValue dependency property to fire.** The problem is that the business logic in the setter is not firing when I do something like -

```
this.FlowSetPointValue = 200;
```

in the view model.

Plus, there are a few odd things that are really throwing me off here, and I'll list them below so that maybe then can shed some light on what I have messed up here.

1. Even though the business logic in the setter of the SetPointValue dependency property is not firing when I try to set the FlowSetPointValue property in the view model (as mentioned above), **the actual value of the SetPointValue dependency property is being set!** I can see that it's being set just fine because there are labels in the user control that are bound to the dependency property and they are displaying it. In other words, as in the code I had above, if I were to set the FlowSetPointValue to 200 then it would display as 200 just fine in the user control, which tells me that the SetPointValue dependency property is indeed being updated with the value.
2. In the code behind of the window, I can set the SetPointValue dependency property like such and the business logic fires in the setter as I would expect it to.

   flowUC.SetPointValue = ((LrsVM)this.DataContext).FlowSetPointValue;

Comment: "in the setter above ... there is some business logic ...". This won't work, because the setter is bypassed when the property is set by a Binding (and some other source).

Comment: @Clements - Thanks for finding the duplicate question for me!! I looked but didn't have any luck finding a question like mine.